# Overlay Fade Out from Centre

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'd like to know how to make an overlay gradually disappear from its centre so that the image behind it becomes visible via an increasing circle from the centre. I know there are existing jQuery methods for example like slideDown() and slideUp(). Are there any existing methods out there for this effect or how else can I go about it?

If you can imagine a black overlay with a hole in the middle showing the image behind it and that hole getting bigger eventually revealing the whole image behind it.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rs_obi/hzgruode/18/) with slide up and down.

HTML:

```
<div id= 'container'>
  <img src=>
  <div id = 'overlay'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#container').mouseenter(_=> {
    $('#overlay').slideUp();
});

$('#container').mouseleave(_=> {
    $('#overlay').slideDown();
})
```

Comment: what have you tried? please add a code to see what you have so far

Comment: @Riskbreaker I'm not really sure where to start. I just need pointing in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider scaling the image up with CSS to keep it simple?

```css
.background {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform: scale(0.01);
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.background:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="background" id="back">
  <img src="https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg"/>
</div>
```